# small hole in model with bezier curve and solidify

Tags: bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I'm trying to model a cup using a simple bezier curve, and then using (in this order) the screw, solidify, subdivision modifiers.

This leaves a tiny hole in the bottom though, should I change my curve or modifiers? Or do I need to 'plug' this using some sculpting?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks as if the origin wasn't exactly at the 3D cursor when you used the screw modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by switching solidify mode from 'simple' to 'complex'. All smooth now!